# What happened to Wolffe & Gregor after Rex left?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

When Rex joined the crew of the Ghost, what happened to the other two clones? One is suffering from PTSD and the other is a lunatic. Did they follow Rex to the Rebel fleet and get moved into the medical bay for retirement or did they stay behind in their AT-TE (if it's not too wrecked to be gone) and continued slinging for Joopas?

Comment: Is there anyway I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 2):

According to a deleted scene, they stayed behind on Seelos and took over one of the AT-ATs.

Comment: Good find. You have my +1

Answer (score 0):

In one of the "Rebels Recon" episodes, I think Filoni or Pablo explained that Wolffe and Gregor stayed behind.

I forgot which RR exactly. But their fate had indeed been explained.

Comment: I've watched the RRs for the two episodes that they appear in and there's no mention of their fate.; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRAcatgArJA&list=PL148kCvXk8pBBJ1-qxpc_fdnlg0WiFWDS&index=14

Comment: No, it was in a later RR, not for the two Season 2 opener episodes.

Comment: Find it. I stand ready to upvote you.

Answer (score -1):

Wiki said they stayed on Seelos , taking the Empire's AT-AT as their new mobile home.
Guess they still want a bit of action than to be sent to some retirement facility.

[Source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/CC-5576-39)

Comment: The [source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/CC-5576-39) references the wiki entry for the episode [Relics of the Old Republic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Relics_of_the_Old_Republic) but there is no info about this on that page.